# BeautifulSoup code question regarding data type

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Now I'm working on the financial table at:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ATVI/financials?p=ATVI

What I don't get is the result of `find_all` method. 
When I put more dot notation on it like `find_all('td').children`
It throws an error. 
Maybe my mistake is from the fact the return value of `find_all` is an object, not a list right?

And I don't have a clue as to why the code below doesn't work.

```
span_tag1=soup.find_all('td')
for i in span_tag1.children:
    print(i.get_text)
```

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, you need to loop through the list to process each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with pandas to get a nicely formatted table then slice out what you want

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ATVI/financials?p=ATVI')
print(tables[0].fillna(''))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're finding `all` `td` elements (which creates a list), you need to loop through each one, and then find the children of each `td` element:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    for child in td.children:
        print(child.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_all()` returns a list, so you need to loop over it. You can then use `children` on the elements, and call `get_text()` on them.

```
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    for child in td.children:
        print(child.get_text())
```

Notice that `get_text()` is also a method, you need parentheses after it.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `span_tag1` list to get each elem inside it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ATVI/financials?p=ATVI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

td = soup.find_all('td')

for et in td:
   for elem in et:
      print(elem.text)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Revenue
12/31/2018
12/31/2017
12/31/2016
12/31/2015
Total Revenue
7,500,000
7,017,000
6,608,000
4,664,000
Cost of Revenue
2,517,000
2,501,000
.
.
```